# Java Modulus Weird

Tags: java, math, modulus

I write code to test methods, display food and price:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class JavaTutorial5Class {

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            greeting("Thunderdome");
            prices("Fatburger", 7.50);
        }
        static void greeting(String restaurant)
        {
            System.out.println("Welcome to "  + restaurant);
        }

        static void prices(String burger, double price){
            System.out.print(burger + " is " + "$" + price);
            //System.out.println(Math.ceil(price % 10));
            if (Math.ceil(price % 10) == 8.0){
                System.out.print("0");
            }
        }
    }
```

Why is `price % 10 == 8.0`? And is this really what you have to do to get the tailing 0 on there?

EDIT: All this code is supposed to do is print "Fatburger is $7.50" the problem is that simply giving it the argument 7.50 converts it to 7.5.

Comment: What is the code supposed to do? it does not make a lot of sense.

Comment: This is a caveat of how the *remainder* operator works (note it's not the *modulus* operator).

Comment: Addressed what it's supposed to do...and I thought it was the modulus operator...what's the difference?

Comment: Perhaps a better question to ask would be, "how do I print my doubles with exactly two digits after the decimal point?" I don't know much about java, but surely there's some nice string formatting operations that can print prices without making you use `%`

Comment: @Kevin right; he should use `System.out.printf` for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this code, the reason you are getting 8.0 is due to you using `Math.ceil`.

`7.5 % 10` is `7.5`, and `Math.ceil(7.5)` is `8.0`.

However, and this is something that comes up extremely often and is a very common mistake for beginners... prices should almost never be stored as doubles. Double arithmetic is not always as precise as you would expect, mainly because of how doubles are actually stored. For example, consider this:

```
double sum = 0.0;
int n = 6;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    sum += 1.0 / n;
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

You would expect it to output `1.0`, but it actually outputs `0.9999999999999999`

The correct way to handle prices is with two `int`s: one for dollars, one for cents.

Comment: Thanks, I honestly don't know what I'm doing with doubles, I'm just following what the guy types. I hadn't thought of splitting the dollars and cents before, good idea

Comment: Or even simpler: use bigdecimal.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
static void prices(String burger, double price){
    System.out.print(burger + " is $" + price);
    if ((int)(price * 10) == price * 10)
        System.out.print(0);
}
```

As you have it now, `7.5 % 10` simply returns `7.5` and the `Math.ceil` rounds this up to `8.0`.

Answer (score 2):

price % 10 is actually 7.5. Modulu is the remainder of division (or how many times a number can fit into another). For example, 22 % 10 is 2, since 10 can fit into 22 twice without going over. Taking the ceiling, which raises it to the nearest integer, raising 7.5 it to 8. Hence the if statement is resulting as true.

Answer (score 2):

I think ultimately the solution he wants (to print a double in the form of currency) can be solved as so...

Add import

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
```

and use this code

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(); 
System.out.print(burger + " is " + "$" + nf.format(price));
```

Forget all the modulo stuff (it is over complicating and incorrect way to achieve what you are asking for).

Also there is a slight rounding issue with doubles and if you need perfect precision (doubtful given the rest of your code), but typically the standard is to use 2 ints to store currency).

Answer (score 2):

Use the following command to format your string correctly:

```
System.out.printf(%s is $%.2f, burger, price)
```

Reference this page for a tutorial on string formatting:  http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_formatted_strings.html

The `%s` will be replaced by the value of `burger`, formatted as a string.

The `%.2f` will be replaced by the value of `price`, formatted as a decimal number with exactly 2 places after the decimal point.